# Placing often duplicated code in function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I often use this code or a form of this code throughout OnClicks and OnLoads:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("administratorGetAll", con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
```

So I was wondering what the best way to minimize such large duplications; function?

I am currently trying something like this:

```
 public void SqlStructGetAll(string storedProc, string connection)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(storedProc, con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not sure if I am way off with this.

Comment: Removed the functional-programming tag. Putting common code into a function does not mean functional programming. That is particular to languages like F#, Lisp and many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are design patterns that solve such design issues where code duplication is major concern.

The pattern applicable to your scenario is template method design pattern from Gang Of Four pattern catalog.

You are in the right direction - please refer to http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx for details on the design pattern.

Most modern day frameworks provide utility wrappers and template methods for operations like database handling - you can use Spring.NET that provides such methods. You can have a look at this link http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.3.0/reference/html/ado.html for example of template method to use ADO.NET API in Spring .NET

Comment: I fear some of this may be slightly more advanced for the websites I am creating. Is there possibly a lighter way without creating business and model layer objects?

Answer (score 0):

By placing your data access in the codebehind for your onclick and onload functions you're tightly coupling your data access layer with your presentation layer. While you're on the right track in thinking that you should pull that type of code out of each function, you might be better of by rethinking your architecture. Dan Wahlin has a [good example of building an n-layer application](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/the-stratifier.aspx) which uses ADO.Net. You might get some good ideas from his code example which may help you in the future.

[Creating an N-Layer ASP.NET Application - Video](http://www.mefeedia.com/watch/33535751)

[Direct Code download](http://www.xmlforasp.net/CodeBank/Download/Blog/ADO.NET%20and%20NLayerDemo.zip)